Google Scholar makes APA formatted reference only a few clicks away
Google Scholar now has a cite button on each reference which makes it easy to get an APA formatted reference.
See the announcment on the blog and this image taken from the blog post:

Implications
I hope that this encourages  more users to add formatted references to questions and answers. 
See also: 

How should references to journal articles be provided?


A good find, Jeromy!  If I run across any old "link only" citations, I will make some attempt to clean them up.

While not quite as important as site promotion, I thought this info might benefit from being featured for a couple of weeks (e.g., until perhaps end of October 2012). Let me know if anyone disagrees.

I think that's a great idea.  Honestly, I think our site is one of the more diligent about writing references properly, but this will help us clean up any corners that we've missed.

This is pretty amazing, Jeromy! :D And @ChuckSherrington I would agree -- you guys are like Skeptics-level of citation OCD. :D

Now all we need is an automatic DOI link to be added. :) (... and while we're at it, an automated search for free PDF versions)

@JeromyAnglim another reason to prefer Google Scholar? ;)

Ugh where was this when I was in collage
